# Sorting List<Type> based on one field of Type

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class:

```
private class Venue
{
    private int venueID;
    private String venueName;
    private String venueLocation;
    private String startDate;
    private int startHour;
    private String startHourType;
    private int startMinute;
    private String endDate;
    private int endHour;
    private String endHourType;
    private int endMinute;
    private String runningTime;
    private double distance;
}
```

And I have a list object of that class:

```
private List<Venue> venueList;
```

I populate venueList with the results of a web service call, some thing like

```
Venue newVenue = new Venue();
newVenue.venueName = "value";
newVenue.distance = 1518.23
//snip
venueList.add(newVenue);
```

Now I want to sort the object venueList based on the .distance field, so I have this:

```
Collections.sort(venueList, new Comparator<Venue>() {
    public int compare(Venue one, Venue other) {
        return Double.compare(one.distance, other.distance);
    }
});
```

However this does not sort as expected, for example the List may look something like:

```
Distance:
1512.9027099609375
702.6363525390625
814.787353515625
605.23388671875
```

And the order of the sorted list is the same. What am I missing?

Edit: The outcome should be the lowest (605.233) up to the highest (1512.902)

Edit: My custom sorting class:

```
public class LocationComparator implements Comparator<Venue> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Venue one, Venue other) {
        return Double.compare(other.distance, one.distance);
    }

}
```

And I call it like so:

```
Collections.sort(venueList, new LocationComparator());
```

Which is correct, right?

Comment: private field and one.distance and other.distance? Can you share whole code? Is that the sorting in same class?

Comment: Your code looks correct. This should work.

Comment: What is sort expected? is it long distance come before or nearest come before?

Comment: Dumb question, but: Are you sure your sorting code is actually executing?

Comment: Your code should work. There are 2 explanations I can think of for why it isn't sorting. (1) Collections.sort is never actually called. (2) when you call sort the distance values are actually all equal. We need to see the class in full to explain this.

Comment: (3) you're printing something other than .distance

Comment: No you are doing something mysterious. Add your program completely. Don't edit the program. Surely it will work if you do so. I agree with   @immibis Comment. You are printing some other object, other than you have sorted.

Comment: Make sure you are compiling properly or check your .class file(byte code) has your changes correctly using any decompiler tool. It seems your source code is different than your .class file.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following statement

```
return Double.compare(one.distance, other.distance);
```

to the following,

```
return Double.compare(other.distance, one.distance);
```

Comment: No Impossible. Double.compare document says `returns the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2` So surely it will work as your needs. Swap will takes place depend upon the value return by the compare method. Check your code you are doing some thing mysterious.

Comment: If you notice in his original output it is not sorted in reverse order, it is simply not sorted at all (702 < 814).

Comment: Yes.. I think he is sorting some other object and printing some other object other than sorted object.

Comment: A Main class demonstrating the question is here: https://gist.github.com/jmini/4be4aebed87b0267cd98

Comment: Yes It is working as your expectation. Just I copied @Jmini code and I ran in my desktop, output is showing in ascending order. Make sure you have compiled properly or check .class(byte code) file has your changes correctly using any decompiler tool?

Answer (score 1):

That's very odd. Here a simple test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> itemsToSort = new LinkedList<Item>();
        for (double d = 100; d > 0; d -= 15) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.doubleValue = d;
            itemsToSort.add(item);
        }

        System.out.println("Before Sort:");
        System.out.println(itemsToSort);

        Collections.sort(itemsToSort, new Comparator<Item>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
                return Double.compare(i1.doubleValue, i2.doubleValue);
            }

        });
        System.out.println("Sorted:");
        System.out.println(itemsToSort);
    }

    private static class Item {
        private double doubleValue;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item: " + doubleValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
Before Sort:

[Item: 100.0, Item: 85.0, Item: 70.0, Item: 55.0, Item: 40.0, Item: 25.0, Item: 10.0]

Sorted:

[Item: 10.0, Item: 25.0, Item: 40.0, Item: 55.0, Item: 70.0, Item: 85.0, Item: 100.0]
```

So it seems to work as documented.

Comment: An other example with the classes from the question can be found here: http://gist.github.com/jmini/4be4aebed87b0267cd98

Comment: I just ran it and it works just like my test example - the final array is sorted. I would rather search for an error in the coding around but not in the sorting itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having your `Venue` class `implements Comparable<Venue>`?  You must override the the `compareTo()` method:

```
public int compareTo (Venue other) {
   return Double.compare(this.distance, other.distance);
}
```

Then when you need to sort your `Collection` you should only have to call:

```
Collections.sort(venueList);
```